# How to convert int or bool to checkState

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to convert int and or bool to checkState

```
int ValueCheck;      
private void gsCheck1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;
    box.CheckState = ValueCheck; // doesn't work
    this.gsCheck2.CheckState = ValueCheck; // should be 1 or 0 ?
}
```

As you can see I want to change (this.gsCheck2) CheckState by changeing (this.gsCheck1) CheckState and end up with a integer value which is need.

Update....
problem solved

```
private int ValueCheck(CheckState Check)
{
    if (Check == CheckState.Checked)
        return 1; 
    else
        return 0; 
}


private void gs_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox box = sender as CheckBox;
    MessageBox.Show(box.Name + "="+ ValueCheck(box.CheckState).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Consider [`CheckBox.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) which is the boolean property.
- Use `box.CheckState = (CheckState)ValueCheck;`
- You can also use the [`?:` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Update according to comments:

Either declare the ValueCheck as a CheckState:

```
CheckState ValueCheck;
private void....
```

Or convert the int value to a CheckState value:

```
this.gsCheck2.CheckState = (CheckState)ValueCheck;
```

The cast back the CheckState value to int:

```
CheckState cs = box.CheckState;
int ValueCheck = (int)cs;
string result = "Current state: " + ValueCheck + cs.ToString();

//You question:
MessageBox.Show(box.Name + (int)box.CheckState);
```

**Update**
FYI, instead of writing the ValueCheck method, there is a C# operator [`?:` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) I mentioned above, which you can do:

```
int result = box.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
```

Which is a translation of:

```
int result;
if (box.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    result = 1;
else
    result = 0;
```

Comment: Why can't you, please explain and we'll try to look for a better option.

Comment: thank but this is not answer to my question. I need a 0 or 1 return. an integer.

Comment: Simply cast it back to int, see my updated answer. In the update the ValueCheck variable contains your integer result and if you don't use interminate (CheckBox.ThreeState property) it will return either 0 or 1, **an integer**.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need CheckedState which also covers the 'partial' checked state some CheckBoxes can have, or are you simply looking for a way without writing a bunch of IF statements to apply values to and from CheckBoxes? If so, have you considered using ConvertTo?

To turn a 0 or 1 into a boolean that can be assigned to a CheckBox:

```
    CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(0);     // False - Not checked.
CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(1);   // True - checked.
```

Or to reliably turn the Checked property of a Checkbox into a 1 or 0:

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(CheckBox1.Checked);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Convert.ToBoolean(urObject);` it is what are you after.

```
if(Convert.ToBoolean(urObject)) {}
```

//above code in C# equivalents to C/C++ code:

```
if(urObject) {} //Which will return false if urObject is null or 0 (for integer), else return true
```

API info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
int ValueCheck=Convert.ToByte(chk.Checked)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears `ValueCheck` should be either 1 or 0 representing `true` and `false` respectively, in which case you should use this:

```
this.gs_check2.Checked = ValueCheck == 1;
```

EDIT: Based on your edit it seems what you want is this:

```
CheckState state = (CheckState)this.ValueCheck;
box.CheckState = state;
this.gsCheck2.CheckState = state;
```

However note that it could be possible that ValueCheck could contain an invalid value for the `CheckState` enumeration.

Comment: ValueCheck has already a positive or negative value so why == 1;

Comment: @Power-Mosfet - What are the values you expect for `ValueCheck`? The comment suggests it should be 0 or 1. You need to update your question to explain how you want the CheckState of the checkbox to be mapped to different possible values of ValueCheck.

Comment: @Power-Mosfet - The box.CheckedState returns an Enum value, which you have to cast to int. besides it may also contain the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

CheckState enum has following values:

```
CheckState.Unchecked = 0,
CheckState.Checked = 1,
CheckState.Indeterminite = 2
```

If you store your values as nullable bit in your DB, this corresponds to bool? in c#.

I wrote the following static Helper Methods for handy conversions between bool? and CheckState

```
public static bool? ConvertCheckStateToNullableBool(CheckState input)
        {
            switch (input)
            {
                case CheckState.Unchecked:
                    return false;
                case CheckState.Checked:
                    return true;
                //case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                //    return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static CheckState ConvertBoolToCheckState(bool? input)
        {
            switch (input)
            {
                case false:
                    return CheckState.Unchecked;
                case true:
                    return CheckState.Checked;
                    //case null:
                    //    return CheckState.Indeterminate;
            }
            return CheckState.Indeterminate;
        }
```